# linux screen see previous lines

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

When I run some task using screen there was some error. I want to see the details but can only roll back one page, the previous ones are all black. Is there any way to see the previous lines?

Comment: This isn't a programming question and is off topic for Stack Overflow. You might have better luck asking at [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure the scrollback buffer for `screen` in your `.screenrc` file:

```
defscrollback 5000
```

Will allow 5000 lines to be scrolled.

Also, during startup, you can use `-h 5000` to specify the buffer for the current `screen` session:

```
screen -h 5000
```

This method is useful for overriding your default setting for a single use (who quits screen?! =P).

Check out this article for good details - [GNU Screen: Working with the Scrollback Buffer](http://www.samsarin.com/blog/2007/03/11/gnu-screen-working-with-the-scrollback-buffer/)

Comment: ah! too fast for .screenrc ;-) Well I'll just add you can also use "|less ", "|grep " etc...

Comment: @BruceXindaLin The file will be located in your user's home directory; you can open it with `gedit ~/.screenrc` or use whatever editor you prefer. It may not exist at first; if not, just throw in that line to the empty file and you should be good.